# Armadillo - fill a matrix from the values in a column vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, armadillo, column-major-order

I would like to go back and forth between an `arma::mat` of size M x N and an `arma::vec` of size MN (which is a column-major linearization of the matrix).

I can easily go from matrix to vector using `arma::vectorise`, i.e.

```
arma::vec vector = arma::vectorise(matrix);
```

However, I cannot find a simple way to go the other way around. I would like to insert the first M values of the vector in the first column of the matrix, the second M values in the second column and so on. Is there a way to do so efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the memory from the matrix to be shared with the vector using [advanced constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col):

```
mat X(4,5);

vec V(X.memptr(), X.n_elem, false, false);

// changing elements in X or V will affect both
```

As long as your operations don't cause aliasing or change the size of either `X` or `V`, the two objects will keep sharing the memory.